# Python, convert single variables into dict

Tags: python

Let's say there are variables with values on Python:

```
lorem = 'ipsum'
dolor = 'sit'
amet = 'consectetur'
```

Which code on Python can convert these variables in a dict? It is assumed all values are strings.

```
{'lorem': 'ipsum', 'dolor': 'sit', 'amet': 'consectetur'}
```

I've found that `inspect` module could be used:

```
import inspect

lorem = 'ipsum'
dolor = 'sit'
amet = 'consectetur'
ans = {k: v for k, v in inspect.currentframe().f_locals.items() if v in [lorem, dolor, amet]}
```

The result is that I want:

```
{'lorem': 'ipsum', 'dolor': 'sit', 'amet': 'consectetur'}
```

But I don't like the filtering I did: `if v in [lorem, dolor, amet]`, it doesn't look nice.
Is it any better way to convert variables to such dict?

Comment: The correct way is to not having had these loose variables in the first place, if you need them in a dict. What's your actual use case here? I doubt it's `lorem`/`dolor`/`amet`.

Comment: (Also, by the way, [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/functions.html#locals) would be easier than `inspect.currentframe()` shenanigans.)

Comment: `... for f in locals() if not f.startswith('_')` would work if those are your _only_ local variables.

Comment: @Codist No, not exactly. In CPython, locals aren't held in a dictionary (for performance reasons); when you call `locals()`, a dictionary is created for you; see [`_PyFrame_GetLocals`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9560e0d6d7a316341939b4016e47e03bd5bf17c3/Objects/frameobject.c#L1203C1-L1288). (This is also why the docs for `locals()` say "The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.".)

Comment: @Codist You also said "They're already in a dictionary." There is no dictionary for locals before you call `locals()`, and even so it's not _the_ dictionary where they are, it's a copy.

Comment: Since you already know the names of the variables you are looking for, why not use a list of strings to build your dictionary?

Answer (score -1):

You can prefix your desired variables, use dir() to get them and eval() to get their values.

```py
var_lorem = "ipsum"
var_olor = "sit"
var_amet = "consectetur"

dir_variables = [variable for variable in dir() if variable.startswith("var_")]

ans = {eval(v): v for v in dir_variables}
print(ans.items())

# dict_items([('consectetur', 'var_amet'), ('ipsum', 'var_lorem'), ('sit', 'var_olor')])
```

Comment: There's no need to use `eval()` – OP already uses (the equivalent of) `locals()`.